# Download manager / url fetcher using a threadpool?

Tags: android

My app fetches image resources (thumbnails for user objects presented in a listview). I created a simple download manager class which accepts urls for the images, fetches them using a single thread, then notifies the client imageviews that they're ready.

I'm wondering if there's an already-published manager class that people are using? Ideally it would use ThreadPoolExecutor internally to allow more than one download at a time (right now my implementation just queues up requests for a single internal worker thread).

I'm missing any implementations of this around the web. I'd imagine it would look like:

```
class DownloadManager {
    DownloadManager(int poolSize);
    void addRequest(String url);
    void addObserver(Observer observer);
}
```

Internally it has a thread pool, and calls observer.notify(String downloadedUrl) whenever a resource has been fetched, for any registered observers. I could put this together myself but I'm guessing someone has already done this.

Thank you for any references

Answer (score 0):

try use the asynktask look like this:

```
public class HttpRequest {
private IHttpRequest delegate;

public <T extends IHttpRequest> HttpRequest(T delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

public void execute(String url){
    new ManagerAsyncTask().execute(url);
}

private class ManagerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            return httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result != null) {
            delegate.executeAction(result);
        }
    }
}
}
```

and whois using implements this interface

```
public interface IHttpRequest {
public void executeAction(String result); //this method execute the return of webservice
}
```

example your class will be:

```
myClass extends Activyt implements IHttpRequest {
    onCreate(){
        new HttpRequest(this).make(http://.......); //here your start the download in background
    }

    public void executeAction(String result){
        Log.i("Tag",result);
        //here you make what you need with result of request
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi ademar, in this setup, wouldn't each request create a new AsyncTask instance? So if I launch 100 requests, all 100 instances will be trying to download in parallel? I thought the benefit of using a threadpool is that threads would be queued until there's space for them to run. Thank you